# iTunes 12 home sharing import album

Tags: itunes, macos, home-sharing

Any idea how to import albums from one computer to another via Home Sharing on Yosemite / iTunes 12? All the pages I've found tell you to click a Show menu at the bottom of the window which is no longer there.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12286
http://support.apple.com/kb/PH986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Home Sharing** is a method to share music directly between Mac's on a local network authenticated with the same iTunes account.

**Family Sharing** is the method for sharing purchases made through iTunes or App Store by a defined group of iTunes accounts all using the same credit card.

**Share My Library** is a preference in iTunes that allows local network user to stream, but not copy, music from your library.

The Home Sharing feature allows one to view, copy, and play music from a locally networked Mac. In iTunes 11 and earlier, it was relatively simple to drag content over to your own library and thus copy the files over the local network. With iTunes 12 it can be a bit less obvious.

With a properly configured pair of Macs on Home Sharing, you can drag a song to the left and a sidebar will reveal allowing you to pick a target location. This function is often broken and requires you unconfigure/reconfigure the Home Sharing.

See [this Apple Discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6612909) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Home-sharing isn't a direct "mac-mac"  designed protocol. It merely allows you (and the family) to download things from iCloud which were previously purchased by any one of you.

The only other way I can think of, which I personally do is import the music directly over the network into iTunes.

Comment: This confuses Home Sharing and Family Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Home Sharing did allow you to easily import music from another computer on your family network. I've just gotten around to trying to import the library from my old MacBook running 10.6.6 with iTunes 10 to my newer MacBook running 10.10.4 with iTunes 12.

The solution I found was to set up the folder containing my music on my old Mac as a shared network folder. On the new Mac, in iTunes, I went to File>Add to Library. I then navigated to the shared music folder on my old Mac and selected all of my music files.